# How to retrieve a list using Wikidata's web API?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I need to simply retrieve this footballers list in JSON format :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_footballers_in_England_by_number_of_league_appearances

So i'm trying out this wikidata query ( with the wikidata ID linked to this page):

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&ids=Q6620948

But i can see no footballer name in the result , only a few descriptions, that's all !

Answer (score 0):

That list isn't actually stored in Wikidata. It's only stored as human edited text on the Wikipedia page.

You can access that content by either using the [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) or [data dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download). You could also just use generic web scraping tools.